# How send method POST with JSON? Arduino UNO R3 + SIM900

Tags: arduino-uno, json

Why is the server side of php not loading any data from arduino? What did I do wrong?

```
  String reading="{\"latitude\": 12.983027,  \"longitude\": 80.2594}";
  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT"); 
  toSerial(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1"); 
  toSerial(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://gerro.usermd.net/updateData.php\"");
  toSerial(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\", \"application/json\"");
  toSerial(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPDATA=" + String(reading.length()) + ",100000");
  toSerial(5000);

  mySerial.println(reading);
  toSerial(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1"); 
  toSerial(15000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
  toSerial(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM"); 
  toSerial(500);
```

**Result:**

```
AT+HTTPINIT

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://gerro.usermd.net/updateData.php"

OAT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT", "application/json"

OK
AT+HTTPDATA=46,100000

DOWNLOAD

OK
AT+HTTPACTION=1

OK

+HTTPACTION:1,200,55
AT+HTTPREAD

+HTTPREAD:55
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
nic ciekAT+HTTPTERM

OK
```

**EDITING**

```
void toSerial(int delay_ms)
  {
    delay(delay_ms);

    while(mySerial.available()) 
    {
       Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    }
  }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
//code
} else {
echo 'nic';
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `toSerial()` do? Post all of it.

Comment: Check your server first, as far as I can tell, your server return an empty array even when I test it with Postman, so it has nothing to do with your arduino code. It is your php code that doesn't handle the POST request correctly.

Comment: @hcheung as it tests with postman it all works and returns data from $ _POST. I think you tested it badly. In the php file there is var_dump ($ _ POST) and hence the result array (0) {}

Comment: @TisteAndii I've already edited the post.

Comment: on the server php shows that it does not receive CONTENT-TYPE and CONTENT-LENGTH from arduino

Comment: Good luck then if you are saying you could get the correct Postman result while I can't even test it correctly. If my Postman test get the same result as your Arduino code, what does that tell you?

Comment: @hcheung maybe you haven't enabled the POST method

Comment: Trust me, I use Postman on daily basis...

Comment: @hcheung however you were right, it was wrong in the php file, instead of $ _POST you had to use file_get_contents("php://input") !

Answer (score 1):

You had to change the php file:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to:

```
echo print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
```

Thank you !